# Replacing a class with Mono.Cecil

Tags: c#, .net, mono.cecil

Say I have assembly A. It was modified with Mono.Cecil a little bit. Now say I have assembly B. It has a class named `SomeClass`. Assembly A also has a class named `SomeClass`. Now I want to replace `SomeClass` from assembly A with the one in assembly B. I tried a few things, but I know that for one of my attempts, it actually remapped a method call like this:

```
Console.WriteLine("Test.");
```

...into this:

```
int.WriteLine("Test.");
```

That can't be right. What is the correct way to replace a class with Mono.Cecil?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably doing something that Cecil doesn't understand. It's impossible to tell you what without seeing any code.

Swapping a type by another is not trivial, you'd have to recreate in the target module the object model you want to inject, and replace every reference of it with the new one. Basically, you'd have to walk over every reference in the target module and make sure it's properly processed.